# entlib wcf integration is throwing exception when trying to pass argument by reference

Tags: wcf, pass-by-reference, enterprise-library

using the Enterprise Library in a WCF service application, we encounter the following exception when we try to use validation on an operation that has arguments passed in by reference:

The operation contract:

```
Hubs GetRoute(
    string sourceDepotId,

    [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "...")]
    [RegexValidator("[a-zA-Z]", MessageTemplate = "...")]
    [StringLengthValidator(2, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 2, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, MessageTemplate = "...")]
    string countryCode,

    string zipCode,
    DateTime shippingDate,
    DateTime? deliveryDate,
    ref RoutingCodes routingCode,
    out string errorMessage);
```

The exception:

> The type 'RoutingCodes&' may not be used as a type argument.

```
[ArgumentException: The type 'RoutingCodes&' may not be used as a type argument.]
   System.RuntimeType.ThrowIfTypeNeverValidGenericArgument(RuntimeType type) +14240432
   System.RuntimeType.SanityCheckGenericArguments(RuntimeType[] genericArguments, RuntimeType[] genericParamters) +57
   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation) +218
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.ValidatorFactory.WrapAndInstrumentValidator(Validator validator, Type type) +87
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.ValidatorFactory.FindOrCreateValidator(ValidatorCacheKey cacheKey, Func`3 wrapAndInstrument) +190
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.ValidatorFactory.CreateValidator(Type targetType, String ruleset) +176
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF.ValidationParameterInspector.CreateInputParameterValidator(ParameterInfo param, String ruleSet) +99
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF.ValidationParameterInspector..ctor(OperationDescription operation, String ruleSet) +221
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF.ValidationBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime) +161
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +5106
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +85
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +48
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +293
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +129
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +733
```

The type stated is a enumeration type. I know that you actually can pass arguments by ref in WCF and it works, as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/designing-service-contracts#out-and-ref-parameters).

Is this a bug in the Enterprise Library Validation Block or what are we doing wrong? How do you circumvent the exception besides not using the validation block?